# Memoir chapter style different heading gap chapter and chapter*

Tags: memoir, chapters

I am using a custom chapter style for my thesis, but I am struggling to get consistent chapter heading gaps between chapters without a number (`chapter*{}`) and chapters with a number (`chapter{}`). See examples below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% chapter style
\makechapterstyle{mit}{%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chaptername\ }
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
   \thechapter
  }%
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par}%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    {\raggedright\large\setSpacing{1.5}\textbf{##1}\\\rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt}}
  }
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip0.5\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}
    \chapterstyle{mit}

    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    \lipsum[1]

    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents*

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{Background}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to get those gaps between the rule and the start of the text consistent between different chapters and table of contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the `printchaptertitle` command.

The updated chapterstyle:

```
\makechapterstyle{mit}{%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chaptername\ }
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
   \thechapter
  }%
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par}%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    {\raggedright\large\setSpacing{1.5}\textbf{##1}}
  }
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt}\par\nobreak\vskip0.5\baselineskip}%
}
```